# RxSwift + MVVM: Efficient way map incoming model to exposed Driver/Observable properties

Tags: rx-swift, reactivex

I'm using RxSwift to bind view models and views, and I have about 10 drivers that expose the properties in my view model:

```
let title: Driver<String>
let description: Driver<String>
let price: Driver<String>
...
```

What is the best way to drive those observables from the incoming sequence of models? Is it best to observe the incoming for every driver? Is this an odd/in-efficient way of doing things?

```
self.title = incoming.productObservable.map({ $0.title }).asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: "")
self.description = incoming.productObservable.map({ $0.description }).asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: "")
self.price = incoming.productObservable.map({ $0.price }).asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: "")
...
```

I can't think of a better way of doing it other than creating private variables, subscribing to the models observable, setting the variables on each next event, and then having to create another set of public Drivers/Observables from the variable, i.e.:

```
let titleDriver: Driver<String>
private let title = Variable<String>("")
...
titleDriver = title.asDriver()
```

But I hate the duplication and amount of code required for each property!

I want to ensure I don't expose the `Variable`s from outside the view model, as you don't want anyone playing with them!

Comment: Do you want to bind your model properties with `UILabel`s in your `viewController`?

Answer (score 0):

I did not try it, but I would do something like this:

Your model:

```
struct Product {
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let price: String
    // ...
}
```

Then I would create a `UIView` subclass with the differents `UILabel` (or `UIWhateverYouWant`).

```
final class ProductDetailView: UIView {

    // MARK: - Properties
    var product: Product? {
        didSet {
            didSetProduct()
        }
    }

    fileprivate var titleLabel = UILabel()
    fileprivate var descriptionLabel = UILabel()
    fileprivate var priceLabel = UILabel()
    // ...

    fileprivate var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    // MARK: - Initialization
    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

And one extension:

```
private extension ProductDetailView {

    func didSetProduct() {
        guard let product = product else { return }
        // Bind the result to our observer property
        Observable.just(product)
            .bindTo(productObserver)
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

    }

    /// A bindable observer for product
    var productObserver: AnyObserver<Product> {

        return UIBindingObserver(UIElement: self) { detailView, product in

            detailView.titleLabel.text = product.title
            detailView.descriptionLabel.text = product.description
            detailView.priceLabel.text = product.price

        }.asObserver()
    }
}
```

Your `viewModel` will have a `Observable<Product>` property (or `Driver<Product>`)

And finally, in your `viewController` you will have a reference to `ProductDetailView`. For instance:

```
class viewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet private weak var detailView: ProductDetailView!
    // ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        viewModel.product
            .bindTo(detailView.productObserver)
            .addDisposableTo(db)

    }
}
```